# How to extract the the data with delimiter

Tags: bash, shell, csv

I am parsing the csv file using while loop in shell script which has data in below format

```
ba04ba54,1234,MMS,"[""some"", ""somet2"", ""somet""]",21556,48834
```

code:

```
while IFS=, read -r id mvid conkey values cretime modified; 
do
echo $id,$mvid,$conkey,$values,$cretime,$modified
```

but values is assigned with

```
"[""some""
```

instead of

```
"[""some"", ""somet2"", ""somet""]" how to achieve this using shell script
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/\"\[\".*\]\"/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

Comment: It works fine but it is not working for othe json format like "[{""abc"":[{""ABC"":""[0].ABCD.[0].value"",""XYZ"":""-ID"",""value"":""test""}}]] can you please explain it

Comment: @jayashri, awk is not made for json parsing, please use json parser for same.